# Tkinter: How to check if user input in an entry widget matches certain info in a database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to create a login system where I have coded it so that when the user creates a new username and password it stores these into a database.

When the user logs in, I want to be able to check whether the users input matches the data that is in the database and if not, show an error message box. How do I do this?

So far I have made this function that gets all info from the database and an if statement that compares what the user typed in with the info already in the database. I want the user to make as many usernames and passwords and still allow the user to log in.

```py
def login():
    data = sqlite3.connect("account.db")
    c = data.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts")
    records = c.fetchall()

    for record in records:
        recorded = record

    if recorded != entry_username.get():
        message = messagebox.showerror("Error", "Incorrect Username or Password")
    elif recorded != entry_password.get():
        message = messagebox.showerror("Error", "Incorrect Username or Password")

    data.commit()
    data.close()
```

This is what my database looks like:

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.title("Database")

data  = sqlite3.connect("account.db")

c = data.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE accounts (
          username text,
          password text
          )""")

data.commit()

data.close()
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: please post the code u have so far here too

Comment: Yes, we need to see how far you've gotten so we can improve and explain.

Comment: 1. Create a window with entry widgets and button.
2. Create a callback for the button.
3. Query the database in the callback.

Comment: have u tried moving the if and elif inside of the `for` loop?but its gonna `showerror` for all the incorrect files at once

Comment: and waht is your table structure, like the name of the columns and all

Comment: Note that you should *never* store plain-text passwords in a database. Whenever the user types in a password, you should immediately hash it, e.g. using  [`hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac), and only store (and compare) that hash.

Comment: You should use `c.execute('SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', (entry_username.get(), entry_password()))` (assume `username` and `password` are the fields in the table `accounts`) and check whether record returned.  Of course you should also consider @RolandSmith advice to hash the password in the database.